# I want to make a Javascript Quiz that randomizes the questions each time

Tags: javascript

I want to make a quiz that randomizes the questions each time. I got something which randomizes the answers but not the questions. Here is what I got so far.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
         <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-                                                                             scale=1">
<title>Made with Thimble</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

```
<p>

</p>
<script>  
  if (!("scramble" in Array.prototype)) {
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "scramble", {
      enumerable: false,
      value: function() {
        var o, i, ln = this.length;
        while (ln--) {
          i = Math.random() * (ln + 1) | 0;
          o = this[ln];
          this[ln] = this[i];
          this[i] = o;
        }
        return this;
      }
    });
  }
  var quiz = [{
    "question": ["What is the full form of IP?","hi"],
    "choices": ["Internet Provider", "Internet Port", "Internet Protocol" , "Other"],
    "correct": "Other"

  }, {
    "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
    "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak" , "Martin Shaba"],
    "correct": "Bill Gates"
  }, {
    "question": "What was your first dream?",
    "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
    "correct": "8 bits"
  }, {
    "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
    "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van Rossum"],
    "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
  }, {
    "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
    "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
    "correct": "Carbon Copy"
  }];

  quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());
  document.write(quiz[prompt("Which one?")].choices);
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you asking three times?

Comment: You've already got the function you need. Just run `quiz.scramble();`

Comment: Next time the system blocks you from posting a question because you don't have enough actual problem description, that's your queue to elaborate more on what you've tried and why you're stuck. The WORST thing you could do is just copy and paste what you already wrote over and over.

Comment: You forgot the line `quiz.scramble()`. Oh, and the bit where you told the reader what the question was. And what you do with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prompt for only once, then store in variable to choose all the quiz elements..

```
quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());    
var x = prompt("Select question number #:");
var ans = ""
function myFunction(item, index) {
    ans += "\n[" + (index+1) + "]: " + item ; 
}
quiz[x].choices.forEach(myFunction);

var y = prompt(quiz[x].question+"\nYour anwser is:"+ans);

if (y == quiz[x].correct){
    alert("Correct!");
}else{
    alert("Wrong! \nThe right answer is "+quiz[x].correct);
}
```

Comment: `prompt` blocks javascript execution, so the question is never asked before requesting the answer :-(

Comment: Thank you all it works now, last night I just felt really tires so I just copy and pasted the question for Injut

Comment: Wanted to go to sleep

Comment: Hi, I'm glad that it works for you now.. Well, I think it would be great if you could 'accept' the answer (the checklist mark), so that other viewers would be easier to find this solution..